# Number of "Impossible" Word Searches

Tags: combinatorics

After looking through a word search for class, I tried to apply the ideas of combinatorics to the creation of an "impossible" word search, i.e. a word search with absolutely no words in it. A trivial example of this would be:

$$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     r & n \\
     l & p
  \end{array} \right]
$$

So my thought is how many such word searches exist for a "matrix" of a given NxN size?

It's easy for a 1x1, as there are 24 (counting "a" and "I" as words), but the problem becomes exponentially (or factorially) harder as soon as you move to 2x2.

Any thoughts? For simplicity, let's assume that we are only working within English and arbitrarily choose http://www.merriam-webster.com/ as our authority on what is and is not a word.

Comment: This is impossible to calculate by hand/a nice combinatorial arguments, simply because there are many, many words and hence too many conditions to form a counting argument. Calculating a lower bound shouldn't be too hard though - if I'm correct in thinking that all words contain some letters from a,e,i,o,u,y, then $20^{N^2}$ would be a lower bound for such 'impossible' word searches. This is already massive for small $N$.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi : just to smile :  english has a few curious words without vowels and y : ie [tsktsks](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tsktsks). There is also cwtch , cwm , crwth ...

Comment: In other words, we could say that the size of the matrix data cannot be lower than the size of the optimal zipped dictionary

Comment: :) @igael Thanks for finding those!